# I am getting following warning in my netbeans project

Tags: java, manifest, mysql-connector

I am trying to make connection  to my mysql program.I am getting warning like this

```html
run:
Mar 16, 2015 7:11:49 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
WARNING: Duplicate name in Manifest: Class-Path.
Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and
that blank lines separate individual sections in both your
manifest and in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry in the jar file.
Mar 16, 2015 7:11:49 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
WARNING: Duplicate name in Manifest: Class-Path.
Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and
that blank lines separate individual sections in both your
manifest and in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry in the jar file.
Mar 16, 2015 7:11:49 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
WARNING: Duplicate name in Manifest: Class-Path.
Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and
that blank lines separate individual sections in both your
manifest and in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry in the jar file.
Mar 16, 2015 7:11:49 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
WARNING: Duplicate name in Manifest: Class-Path.
Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and
that blank lines separate individual sections in both your
manifest and in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry in the jar file.
Mar 16, 2015 7:11:49 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
WARNING: Duplicate name in Manifest: Class-Path.
Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and
that blank lines separate individual sections in both your
manifest and in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry in the jar file.
Mar 16, 2015 7:11:49 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
WARNING: Duplicate name in Manifest: Class-Path.
Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and
that blank lines separate individual sections in both your
manifest and in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry in the jar file.
Mar 16, 2015 7:11:49 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
WARNING: Duplicate name in Manifest: Class-Path.
Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and
that blank lines separate individual sections in both your
manifest and in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry in the jar file.
Username exist
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I have configured mysqlconnector correctly also tried replacing it.

```html
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

above is my manifest file.